# In the context of stellar nucleosyntheis, is Xenon-130 a primary or secondary isotope?

Tags: star, nucleosynthesis

With the definitions: 'a primary isotope is any isotope which can be synthesised in a star which starts its life containing only hydrogen and helium', and a secondary isotope is any isotope which requires a higher metallicity at the start of the stars life in order to be synthesised.

Is xenon-130 therefore a primary or secondary isotope? Ive read conflicting answers. My reasoning is that to produce xenon-130 you just need a star which can produce iron-56 (therefore just a sufficient mass), and then the s-process, which simply requires an abundance of neutrons, both situations can occur in a first generation star. However many people say that it is secondary.

Can anyone shed any light to clarify?

(im also realising that this may not be the correct forum to ask this question, if not can anyone point me to a relevant place to ask this)